# Can I use conditional generic to set a callback return type in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react component to which I'm passing a generic. Based on this generic I would like to change the callback payload type.

In the example below I'm passing the RelationType which can be 'one' or 'many' and based on this the callback should be either a string or array of strings.

```js
import React from 'react';

export enum RelationType {
  one = 'one',
  many = 'many',
}

interface Props<R extends RelationType> {
  callback(newValue?: R extends RelationType.one ? string : string[]): void;
  relationType: R;
}

export const Component = <R extends RelationType>({ onUpdate, relationType }: Props<R>) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => {
      if (relationType === RelationType.one) {
        callback('foo'); // TS2345: Argument of type '"foo"' is not assignable to parameter of type '(R extends RelationType.one ? string : string[]) | undefined'.
      } else {
        callback(['foo', 'bar']); // TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'R extends RelationType.one ? string : string[]'.
      }
    }}/>
  )
};
```

Is this possible with Typescript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic type parameter `R` in the `Props` type and the `Component` function is not helping you.  Inside of `Component()` you are trying to check `relationType` to narrow `callback`, but generic type parameters like `R` are never narrowed via control flow analysis in TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085) for more information.

Instead it would be best to just use a non-generic `Props` of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) type, equivalent to your original `Props<RelationType.one> | Props<RelationType.many>`:

```
type Props = { [R in RelationType]: {
  callback(newValue?: R extends RelationType.one ? string : string[]): void;
  relationType: R;
} }[RelationType];

/* type Props = {
    callback(newValue?: string | undefined): void;
    relationType: RelationType.one;
} | {
    callback(newValue?: string[] | undefined): void;
    relationType: RelationType.many;
} */
```

In the above I've had the compiler calculate that union programmatically by [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) your original `Props<R>` definition over `RelationType` to form an object type whose properties I immediately [look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).

---

Then your `Component()` function can use a parameter of type `Props`.  Another caveat is that you cannot destructure it into `relationType` and `callback` inside the implementation signature if you want the compiler to keep track of the relationship between the two values.  TypeScript doesn't have support for what I've been calling *correlated union types* (see [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)).  You need to keep both values as properties of a single `props` parameter if you want the behavior you're looking for:

```
const Component = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => {
      if (props.relationType === RelationType.one) {
        props.callback('foo');
      } else {
        props.callback(['foo', 'bar']);
      }
    }} />
  )
};
```

That works as desired, I think.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Amazing,  thanks! I actually tried it with discriminated union type but ran into destruction caveat. Thank you very much for your help! 